# Type mismatch even when Vector type has been declared

Tags: scala

I have a very simple method in a class:

```
def partysCandidate(party: String): Vector[Candidate]= {
    var result = Vector[Candidate]()

    for (candidate <- this.candidates) {

      if (candidate.party == party) result = result + candidate
    }

    result
  }
```

However it gave me Error type mismatch `found   : package.Candidate required: String` at `result + candidate`. I couldn't figure out why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is no method `+` on a `Vector`, there are `+:` (prepend), `:+` (append) (colon is treated as mnemonic for collection), etc.

There is however [`any2stringadd` implicit class](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/Predef$$any2stringadd.html) which - when you call `sth.+(x: String)` on something which doesn't have such method - call `.toString` on `sth` before appending `x` to it, which would return `String`. This results in the error you see. Accidental usage of this extension method is a reason why this got deprecated and why many linters [defend against it](https://www.wartremover.org/doc/warts.html#stringplusany).

Your code could be fixed by using the right operator e.g.

```
if (candidate.party == party) result = result :+ candidate
```

however in this particular case you can just use for-comprenension to build the result without mutation

```
def partysCandidate(party: String): Vector[Candidate] =
   for {
     candidate <- candidates
     if candidate.party == party
   } yield candidate
```

or even shorter

```
def partysCandidate(party: String): Vector[Candidate] =
  candidates.filter(c => c.party == party)
```